# cef python - Freeze when resizing

Tags: python, interface, freeze, chromium-embedded

Today I am trying to develop an UI using cefpython which allows me to embed a web browser and interacts with it with javascript bindings.

I'm using it to develop on Windows platform.
For this purpose, I am using the "multi_threaded_message_loop" flag which allows me to gain in performance.
I'm also using wxpython on python 3 to embed it.

The problem is when I resize my window, the use of **WindowUtils.OnSize()** freezes my app. 99% of the time, it happens when the browser is loading (but it also happens when it's done (rarely)).

Here is a sample code to reproduce :

```
import platform
import sys

import wx
from cefpython3 import cefpython

WindowUtils = cefpython.WindowUtils()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

import os

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    browser = None
    mainPanel = None

    def createMainBrowser(self):
        self.browser = self.createBrowser(self.mainPanel)

    def createBrowser(self, parent):
        browser = cefpython.CreateBrowserSync(
            self.getWindowInfo(parent),
            browserSettings={},
            navigateUrl='http://www.google.com'
        )
        return browser

    def getWindowInfo(self, parent):
        windowInfo = cefpython.WindowInfo()
        windowInfo.SetAsChild(parent.GetHandle(), [0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT])
        return windowInfo

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(
            self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title='wx', size=(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        )
        self.mainPanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainPanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)

        cefpython.PostTask(cefpython.TID_UI, self.createMainBrowser)

        self.mainPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

    def OnSize(self, _):
        if not self.browser:
            return

        WindowUtils.OnSize(self.mainPanel.GetHandle(), 0, 0, 0)
        self.browser.NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted()


class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.excepthook = cefpython.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
    cefpython.Initialize({
        "locales_dir_path": cefpython.GetModuleDirectory() + "/locales",
        "browser_subprocess_path": cefpython.GetModuleDirectory() + "/subprocess",
        "auto_zooming": "system_dpi",
        "multi_threaded_message_loop": True,
    })
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
    cefpython.Shutdown()
```

Thank you a lot for your help !

Alann

Comment: Try use PostTask to execute OnSize and see if it makes difference. Also make sure it is not NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted causing the issue.

Comment: Thx for answering Czarek ! No it's definitly not NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted which is causing the issue. I tried to run OnSize via a PostTask too as suggested. Nothing changes, same crashes.

Comment: And if you remove the call to OnSize it doesn't crash anymore? Try returning True in that event. Here is the source code for OnSize: https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/b1156d389b613950109c3e24cbcc21fd9951263c/src/window_utils_win.pyx#L18 - basically a few windows API calls. You could build from sources and debug it.

Comment: You could make the same Windows API calls using PyWin32 extension in Python (another way to debug it).

Comment: Yes, if I remove the call to WindowUtils.OnSize(), it doesn't crash anymore (but it doesn't resize either, of course).
Returning True doesn't change anything.
I'll try to find an homemade solution as you suggest, as soon as I'll have time for this. Thx

Comment: After further tests, I can see that the crash occurs when a resize is occurring while the browser is loading.

Comment: Problem solved !
Using : win32gui.SetWindowPos(self.browser.GetWindowHandle(), 0, 0, 0, w, h, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved !
Instead of using

```
def OnSize(self, _):
    if not self.browser:
        return

    WindowUtils.OnSize(self.mainPanel.GetHandle(), 0, 0, 0)
    self.browser.NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted()
```

I use

```
def OnSize(self, sizeEvent):
    if not self.browser:
        return

    w = sizeEvent.GetSize().GetWidth()
    h = sizeEvent.GetSize().GetHeight()
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(self.browser.GetWindowHandle(), 0, 0, 0, w, h, 0)
    self.browser.NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted()
```

I don't know if this is because I'm on windows 10 but maybe WindowsUtils needs to be updated !

Comment: Just to confirm, freeze issue doesn't occur when multi threaded message loop is set to False?